# GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9 (booting from USB)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I attempted to install the latest version of Ubuntu, on my laptop which had Windows 7 on it: the installation procedure went fine, it was right at the end when `update-grub` collapsed.

Now it's stuck with this message:

```
GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible 
device or file completions.

grub>_
```

None of the options in the boot menu are successfull.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your dual boot installation procedure. Τry booting your system with a Windows 7 disk and select *Repair your computer* → *System repair* → *Command prompt*.

Now at command prompt type:

```
C:\BOOTREC /FIXMBR
```

If this doesn't work, try these options one by one:

- `/FixMbr`
- `/FixBoot`
- `/ScanOS`

If things get worse, then you have to Rebuild:

- `/RebuildBcd`

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to fix anything from that prompt (it is high-level kung-fu).
You need to boot again from installation medium and do a procedure called "grub repair". A lot of tutorials on the net, for example [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) one. If it fails again, ask another question with details on what you do and what errors you see.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu and if you can spare 30 GB or more in your hard drive, do not create any separate partition for swap or home. Remember you should have a RAM of 4GB or more.
Just create **/root** alone and Ubuntu itself will take care of everything. After creating root /, Ubuntu will show in the menu as "boot from 250 or 500(maximum of your hard drive) GB from hard drive". Do not change this also since Windows boot will be in some other place other than Ubuntu partition.

Grub will take over the entire booting process and it will transfer the boot to Windows in case if you want windows to boot at the time of start up. I had the same problem and I was committing this mistake. Once I found this, I changed and the grub worked like charm.  Hope this helps. All the best.